# Where to report Salesforce documentation mistake/typo?

Tags: documentation

Reading through Salesforce documentation, I've found several mistakes and typos. Where to report them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of most pages there is a "share your feedback" button where you can report a problem.  See screenshot.

[image]